# Kibana filter before Date Histogram?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, kibana-3

I want to run a filter first, e.g. `tag:foo`, and for all matched rows, then I run a `Date Histogram`, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37883308/6113627):

Go to the Discovery page and enter the search query : `tag:foo`

Once you've entered your query in the discovery page, save your current search:
[Kibana documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#save-search)

Then when creating the visualisation, after selecting the type `Date Histogram`, you use "From a saved search" to select the search you've created.
In that case only the documents from the search will be on the graph.